# Decompressing gz SQL file

Tags: compression, gzip, gunzip

So I want to decompress my `something.gz` file. Whenever I try to do this by using gunzip it ends after a little while saying there was an unexpected end of the file. The file itself is about 4gb.

Would appreciate any help regarding this problem.

Command: `gunzip < db-20180518060048.sql.gz > db-20180518060048.sql`

> Response: gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
>
> Ends at: ('250

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also add the command you've tried and the error message you get.

Comment: Are you using a file system which supports files > 4GB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `-d` to decompress:

Your command would be:

`gunzip -d db-20180518060048.sql.gz`

**Edit** due to comment:

To test validity of your archive you can run

`gunzip -t db-20180518060048.sql.gz`

`-t --test        test compressed file integrity`

The correct is only **no output**.  Any other means that your archive is damaged.

Comment: Received the same response.

Comment: @Daniel what filesystem do you have?  You can also check integrity with `gunzip -t db-20180518060048.sql.gz` (if output is empty then the archive is valid)

Comment: Using the filesystem ext4 (Linux ubuntu 16)

Comment: Ok, then you are safe.  (ext4 supports up to 16TB).  Is your archive valid?

Comment: Receiving same response: unexpected end of file. What does it imply to not be valid?

Comment: @Daniel Then you archive is not valid.  You need to get other copy of it. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I went back and got another backup of the file. It seemed that something must have gone wrong during my previous backup because it works fine now:) Ty

Comment: @Daniel great!  I'm glad to hear that.  Don't forget to vote: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As your file is quite big, it might be worth writing it to standard output and piping it directly into the database. You can do this with the following command:

```
gzip -c db-20180518060048.sql.gz | mysql (args..)
```

This can be done with gunzip also, I just use gzip as a personal preference. Use man gzip to get more detail on this command.